# want to print a json mutable dictionary in table cells

Tags: iphone

I have a json parsed value that I stored in a dictionary.

Now I want to print the values of that dictionary in a table cell.

This is my dictionary:

```
    "": { 
        "activity_type": "friend accept",
        "owner_id": "33",
        "owner_first_name": "Girija",
        "owner_last_name": "S",
        "photo_url": "http://184.73.155.44/hcl-meme/QA_TEST/sites/default/files/pictures/picture-33-6361851323080768.jpg",
        "activity_id": "35340",
        "activity_details": "a:2:{s:4:\"html\";s:51:\"!user_fullname and !friend_fullname are now friends\";s:4:\"type\";s:10:\"friend_add\";}",
        "time": "1302496707" 
    },
    "1": {
        "activity_type": "friend accept",
        "owner_id": "412",
        "owner_first_name": "Siva Shankara",
        "owner_last_name": "Nainar Bernadsha",
        "photo_url": "http://184.73.155.44/hcl-meme/QA_TEST/sites/default/files/pictures/picture-412249965611.jpg",
        "activity_id": "35339",
        "activity_details": "a:2:{s:4:\"html\";s:51:\"!user_fullname and !friend_fullname are now friends\";s:4:\"type\";s:10:\"friend_add\";}",
        "time": "1302332540" 
    },
    "2": {
        "activity_type": "status_update",
        "activity_id": "35338",
        "user_id": "1",
        "user_first_name": "Chandra Bhusan",
        "user_last_name": "Pandey",
        "photo_url": "http://184.73.155.44/hcl-meme/QA_TEST/sites/default/files/pictures/picture-1627435117.jpg",
        "activity_details": "Hi",
        "time": "1302183038" 
    },
    "boolean": "1" 
    }

Now I want print  

    {
        "activity_type": "friend accept",
        "owner_id": "33",
        "owner_first_name": "Girija",
        "owner_last_name": "S",
        "photo_url": "http://184.73.155.44/hcl-meme/QA_TEST/sites/default/files/pictures/picture-33-6361851323080768.jpg",
        "activity_id": "35340",
        "activity_details": "a:2:{s:4:\"html\";s:51:\"!user_fullname and !friend_fullname are now friends\";s:4:\"type\";s:10:\"friend_add\";}",
        "time": "1302496707"
    }
```

These values in a single cell and similarly the other cells hold the iterated values.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Pls format your json and u can try using json parser to get the response as NSDictionary.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the `NSDictionary` which contains all these values and you want to display all of them on the table cell then I think its better if you create custom UITableViewCell for the cells of your table view. You can get a lot of tutorial for this. Here are some samples

[Tutorial 1](http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/30/iphone-sdk-tutorial-part-6-creating-custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder-uitableview/)

[Tutorial 2](http://iphone.zcentric.com/2008/08/05/custom-uitableviewcell/)